# ExceptionInitializerError triggering javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType incompatible with javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere, classloader

Any suggestions on how to solve this, I am unclear on where else to look.  I am using a WAS 6.1 App Server, 1.5 jdk in RAD 8.

```
SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet SchedulerServlet: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:218)
    at com.met.ca.b2b.managers.ShedulerManager.loadParams(ShedulerManager.java:191)
    at com.met.ca.scheduler.servlet.SchedulerServlet.init(SchedulerServlet.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:350)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:183)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:902)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:824)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:542)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1250)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1167)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:587)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:834)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2100)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType incompatible with javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    at $Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.LocatableAnnotation.invoke(LocatableAnnotation.java:72)
    at $Proxy5.value(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getAccessType(ClassInfoImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:239)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:286)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
    at com.met.ca.common.util.JAXBUtil.initJAXB(JAXBUtil.java:132)
    at com.met.ca.common.util.JAXBUtil.<clinit>(JAXBUtil.java:121)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:196)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: show code please and stack trace too

Comment: It looks much like you have 2 different classloaders that load `AccessType` and `XmlAccessType`. One could have come from app server's common libs, another - from your web application (try to remove corresponding jar to prevent duplication).

Comment: No luck in removing corresponding jars, still getting the same error.

Comment: There are no two ways about it: it might be hard to find but, for sure, you have a JAR file somewhere in your application that contains the JAXB API. It can be either in the EAR/WAR you're deploying, or in the `ws.ext.dirs`, or in a Shared Library attached to your server.